# Kohana: Omit action from url

Tags: php, routes, kohana

Is there any way I can default a route to use action_index and not have to specify it in the url?

ie.

```
Route::set('user_profile','(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'public',
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

To use that I need to specify `/users/index/1234`

But I'd like to use `/users/1234`

I tried taking out action from the Route::set() but I ended up with a 404 page.

**UPDATE**

Now that I have added this route (the top one) my default route doesn't seem to be working now

```
Route::set('user_profile','(<controller>(/<id>))')
->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'public',
    'controller' => 'users',  // Note I changed it to plural to match 'users/*' from your url
    'action'     => 'index',
));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'public',
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as omitting the `<action>` param from the URL, but still keeping the default value:

```
Route::set('user_profile','(<controller>(/<id>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'public',
        'controller' => 'users',  // Note I changed it to plural to match 'users/*' from your url
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Note, that unless you have other Route that overrides this behaviour, your `user` controller will only be able to execute the `index` action.

---

**Edit**

If your `users_profile` route is only handling `/users` path then you can set it in the route explicitly:

```
Route::set('user_profile','users(/<id>)')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'public',
        'controller' => 'users',  // Note I changed it to plural to match 'users/*' from your url
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

This should address the conflicting routes.

Comment: This does work however it seems to be conflicting with another route. I've updated my question

Comment: Now you can change controller name back to `Controller_Public_User`, cause its no present in route pattern.